# Why doesn't "%0.2f" % (.3) return "0.29"?

Tags: python, floating-point

The IEEE 754 floating point value for 0.3 is around 0.29999999999999998.

Based on this, it seems like Python *should* print "0.29" when you execute `"%0.2f" % (.3)`. But, it actually prints "0.30".

What did Python do behind the scenes to get that string representation?

**EDIT**: The [very last sentence of Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) is interesting:

> In current versions, Python displays a value based on the shortest
>   decimal fraction that rounds correctly back to the true binary value

Comment: please explain why do you think that the output is incorrect.

Comment: `a = .3` is really `a = 2.999999...`. When I write "%.2f", I didn't explicitly ask Python to do any rounding for me. The [documentation for %f](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) doesn't mention rounding either.

Comment: Yes, that's an omission in the docs: they *should* mention rounding.  (The corresponding docs in the C standard explicitly mention rounding.)  But would you really prefer an answer that's out by `0.01` to an answer that's out by around `0.000000000000000011` in this case?

Comment: even if they don't mention it, it's still the least astonisment... you specified the precision (and not some abrupt slicing of digits), within that precision `0.3` is the right answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rounding. Python rounds the number, and 0.29999 rounded to two decimal digits is 0.30.

Comment: this isn't python specific.

Comment: OP asked specifically about Python, hence the specific answer.

Comment: Is there some internal round function that Python doesn't expose? Because `round(0.3, 2)` is still .299999...

Comment: In Python >= 2.7, there are internal string-to-float and float-to-string functions `_Py_dg_strtod` and `_Py_dg_dtoa` (respectively) that are used for both string formatting and for `round`.  See [Python/dtoa.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/dtoa.c) in the source tree for the gory details.

Comment: @user2733517: and is should be that. it rounded it to `0.3`, and, as you already said in your question, the internal representation for that is `.299999`...

Answer (score 3):

Conversion to decimal is usually implemented “to the nearest”: if you request a decimal representation with two decimal places, you get the nearest decimal number in that format. For the conversion of the double represented as `0.29999999999999998`, that number is `0.30`.

Actually, the C language is a bit strange to have made fashionable to round “towards zero” for the conversion from float to integer, because there is no particular advantage in doing so either. But this has influenced many programming languages that came after it, including Python, to convert from float to integer by truncation. The conversion from float to integer and its truncation semantics should be considered the exception, and round-to-nearest the general case for all other conversions, including to and from decimal.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I have no idea what makes you think that I think there's a difference.